# Photoshop: Slices of custom sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I try to use slices, it won't me select custom sizes in both Hoz and Vert aspects. In the UI that asks for # of Slices or pixels, I can never set custom Horz / Vert pixels. If I pick 500 Horz and 500 Vert, it changes the vert without asking me, I can't ever get it to be square at the size I want. Is there a work around for  this?

Comment: What UI are you referring to? Is the control bar set to   Fixed Aspect Ration?

Comment: I can't post images, but here. http://i.stack.imgur.com/bLBUV.png I can't make both Pixel fields match. PS always forces one or the other into another size. Or I enter it, save it. and It doesn't change. This is CS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dividing slices you are restricted to the size of the slice you are dividing.

In other words, you are cutting up a specifically sized area. The values in the Divide Slice dialog widow are not absolute values. If you enter 2 for horizontal, then the size is horizontally cut into 2 even pieces. The vertical value is automatically calculated based on Original slice size divided by number of horizontal divisions.

If you want **exact** slice sizes you need to *not* use the divide slice option.

Comment: What method should I use for just breaking up an image into predefined square, regardless of image size or ratio?

Comment: Well you need to explain "predefined square". If you have an image and want to break it up into 5 equal sized pieces, then divide slice is fine. Just stop thinking in terms of dimensions and think in terms of pieces. Divide slice - Horizontal enter 5... hit OK. You get 5 equal sized pieces.

Comment: If you want a slice of very specific pixel dimensions, don't use Divide slice. Simply double-click the slice with the Slice Select Tool and enter the dimensions you want in the W and H fields in the window which pops up.

Comment: That is the way I used to do it, but I am dividing up a 5000x8000 pixel image into square, so that is time consuming to do each slice, the divide tool works great if the dimensions are right, maybe that is my only solution.